# Different InfoPath view depending on SharePoint library it is viewed from

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, form, view

I have a SharePoint form library with an InfoPath form that has several different views (call them V1, V2, V3). Currently I also have another form library that has a form that consists of one of the views from the other library's form (V3). In the ideal state, a user could go to the second library to fill this out by itself OR if certain conditions are met when filling out the first library's form V1 it will send V3 to the second library.

I currently have some rules set up in the first library's V1 that does allow it to send the V3 to the second library but the problem becomes that I don't see a way where we won't have to maintain both V3 on the first library and the second library's own InfoPath form separately.  Is there a way to make both libraries use the same form but have the second library default to showing just V3?

Answer (score 0):

This was achivable in Sharepoint on prem but only with code behind where you would hook to the form onload event.

With SPOnline it may be more tricky. But have you tried this?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c178b7b9-3e38-4fc5-997e-ad213b0f9f85/set-default-infopath-form-view-based-on-page-or-view-called-from?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

if you are showing the iP form in webpart it seems you can specify different default view.